# Search for array in jsonb field (address components from Google maps)

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-maps, jsonb

I have a table `events` with a `location_details` jsonb field, sometimes empty, sometimes filled with records like this:

```json
{
  "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png",
  "name": "Boulevard Pershing",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 48.8805276,
      "lng": 2.283755
    },
    "viewport": {
      "east": 2.285103980291502,
      "west": 2.282406019708498,
      "north": 48.8818765802915,
      "south": 48.8791786197085
    }
  },
  "html_attributions": [

  ],
  "address_components": [
    {
      "types": [
        "route"
      ],
      "long_name": "Boulevard Pershing",
      "short_name": "Boulevard Pershing"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ],
      "long_name": "Paris",
      "short_name": "Paris"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_2",
        "political"
      ],
      "long_name": "Département de Paris",
      "short_name": "Département de Paris"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ],
      "long_name": "Île-de-France",
      "short_name": "IDF"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ],
      "long_name": "France",
      "short_name": "FR"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ],
      "long_name": "75017",
      "short_name": "75017"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to let users search events by location, but not by precise location (e.g. "route" in this example).

any idea on how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I parsed the `address_components` so that they can be easily accessed in SQL:

```json
{
  "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png",
  "name": "Boulevard Pershing",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 48.8805276,
      "lng": 2.283755
    },
    "viewport": {
      "east": 2.285103980291502,
      "west": 2.282406019708498,
      "north": 48.8818765802915,
      "south": 48.8791786197085
    }
  },
  "html_attributions": [

  ],
  "address_components": [
    {
      "types": [
        "route"
      ],
      "long_name": "Boulevard Pershing",
      "short_name": "Boulevard Pershing"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ],
      "long_name": "Paris",
      "short_name": "Paris"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_2",
        "political"
      ],
      "long_name": "Département de Paris",
      "short_name": "Département de Paris"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ],
      "long_name": "Île-de-France",
      "short_name": "IDF"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ],
      "long_name": "France",
      "short_name": "FR"
    },
    {
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ],
      "long_name": "75017",
      "short_name": "75017"
    }
  ],
  "address_components_parsed": {
    "route": {
      "short_name": "Boulevard Pershing",
      "long_name": "Boulevard Pershing"
    },
    "locality": {
      "short_name": "Paris",
      "long_name": "Paris"
    },
    "political": {
      "short_name": "FR",
      "long_name": "France"
    },
    "administrative_area_level_2": {
      "short_name": "Département de Paris",
      "long_name": "Département de Paris"
    },
    "administrative_area_level_1": {
      "short_name": "IDF",
      "long_name": "Île-de-France"
    },
    "country": {
      "short_name": "FR",
      "long_name": "France"
    },
    "postal_code": {
      "short_name": "75017",
      "long_name": "75017"
    }
  }
}
```

revelant ruby code:

```rb
  def location_details=(value)
    return if value.blank?
    value =
      value.is_a?(String) ? JSON.parse(value.presence || "{}") : (value || {})
    value["address_components_parsed"] =
      address_components_for(value["address_components"])
    super(value)
  rescue JSON::ParserError
    errors.add(:location_details, I18n.t("events.errors.is_not_valid_json"))
    super(value)
  end

  def address_components
    (location_details || {}).fetch("address_components_parsed", {})
  end

  def address_components_for(address_components)
    (location_details || {})
      .fetch("address_components", {})
      .each_with_object({}) do |el, acc|
        el["types"].each do |type|
          acc[type] ||= {}
          acc[type]["short_name"] = el["short_name"]
          acc[type]["long_name"] = el["long_name"]
        end
      end
  end
```